# How to make javascript search multiple columns and rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to make all 5 columns and rows searchable. At the moment it only searches via the first column (`DATE`). Could someone please assist me with possibly making it search all the columns and rows please? I have included the HTML, CSS and javascript to try to provide as much information as possible.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
    background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
    background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
    text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
    padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
    /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
    /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:20%;">Date</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Home</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Time</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Away</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">City</th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08/01/2018</td>
    <td>SPAIN</td>
    <td>16:30 ET</td>
    <td>USA</td>
    <td>BARCELONA</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>08/02/2018</td>
    <td>BOLIVIA</td>
    <td>18:30 ET</td>
    <td>PORTUAL</td>
    <td>MADRID</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>08/03/2018</td>
    <td>PUERTO RICO</td>
    <td>18:30 ET</td>
    <td>CANADA</td>
    <td>CHICAGO</td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>08/04/2018</td>
    <td>MEXICO</td>
    <td>19:30 ET</td>
    <td>ENGLAND</td>
    <td>LONDON</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe you mean "Javascript", not "Java".  They're completely different languages. 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using your existing code, loop through the table cells just as you loop through the table rows.

Below, I hide each row. For each row, if text in a cell matches the search term, that row is shown and the loop [continues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) to the next row.

I'm also ignoring the table header by using [`tBodies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies) to limit the search to `<tr>` elements that are within the first `<tbody>`. Alternatively, you could check that `<td>` elements exist in the row before searching; something like: `if (tds.length) > 0`.

```js
function performSearch() {

  // Declare search string 
  var filter = searchBox.value.toUpperCase();

  // Loop through first tbody's rows
  for (var rowI = 0; rowI < trs.length; rowI++) {

    // define the row's cells
    var tds = trs[rowI].getElementsByTagName("td");

    // hide the row
    trs[rowI].style.display = "none";

    // loop through row cells
    for (var cellI = 0; cellI < tds.length; cellI++) {

      // if there's a match
      if (tds[cellI].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

        // show the row
        trs[rowI].style.display = "";

        // skip to the next row
        continue;

      }
    }
  }

}

// declare elements
const searchBox = document.getElementById('searchBox');
const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
const trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

// add event listener to search box
searchBox.addEventListener('keyup', performSearch);
```

```css
#searchBox {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable th {
  width: 20%;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Home</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Away</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>08/01/2018</td>
      <td>SPAIN</td>
      <td>16:30 ET</td>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>BARCELONA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08/02/2018</td>
      <td>BOLIVIA</td>
      <td>18:30 ET</td>
      <td>PORTUAL</td>
      <td>MADRID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08/03/2018</td>
      <td>PUERTO RICO</td>
      <td>18:30 ET</td>
      <td>CANADA</td>
      <td>CHICAGO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>08/04/2018</td>
      <td>MEXICO</td>
      <td>19:30 ET</td>
      <td>ENGLAND</td>
      <td>LONDON</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

### 100% working for unlimited columns !

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search ..." onkeyup="searchTableColumns()">
```

```
<table id="myTable">
     .....
     .....
     .....
</table
```

```
function searchTableColumns() {
      // Declare variables 
      var input, filter, table, tr, i, j, column_length, count_td;
      column_length = document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells.length;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) { // except first(heading) row
        count_td = 0;
        for(j = 1; j < column_length-1; j++){ // except first column
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
            /* ADD columns here that you want you to filter to be used on */
            if (td) {
              if ( td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)  {            
                count_td++;
              }
            }
        }
        if(count_td > 0){
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`, you only select the date column, wich is why it only search in that one. You are going to have to loop through all the coumn and set a boolean to true if you find it at least once.

Something like that:

```
var found = false;
var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
for(j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
    if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        //if found at least once it is set to true
        found = true;
    }
}
//only hides or shows it after checking all columns
if(found){
    tr[i].style.display = "";
} else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response it now works as planned. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

a compact version of the above code, credit to #showdev

```
/**
 * HTML Search for any table
 * 
 * @param element searchBox
 * @param string tableBody
 */
function performSearch(searchBox,tableBody) {
    let trs = $('#'+tableBody).find('tr');
    // Declare search string 
    let filter = searchBox.value.toUpperCase();
    // Loop through first tbody's rows
    for (let rowI = 0; rowI < trs.length; rowI++) {
        // define the row's cells
        let tds = trs[rowI].getElementsByTagName("td");
        // hide the row
        trs[rowI].style.display = "none";

        // loop through row cells
        for (let cellI = 0; cellI < tds.length; cellI++) {
            // if there's a match
            if (tds[cellI].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                // show the row
                trs[rowI].style.display = "";
                // skip to the next row
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like onkeyup="performSearch(this,'smsTableBody')"