# Running javascript in html from browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working javascript here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7oz40y8/) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102742/how-to-make-javascript-search-multiple-columns-and-rows-in-a-table) and would like to run locally with my browser.

I'm not quite sure what else I need to add to the HTML in order for it to run properly. I read many posts but still couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Below is what I have done but there are errors when running the code snippet, can someone help pls? Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function myFunction() {

  // Declare variables 
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through first tbody's rows
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

    // define the row's cells
    var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    // hide the row
    trs[i].style.display = "none";

    // loop through row cells
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

      // if there's a match
      if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

        // show the row
        trs[i].style.display = "";

        // skip to the next row
        continue;

      }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable th {
  width: 20%;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <p><input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." /></p>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Away</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>08/01/2018</td>
        <td>SPAIN</td>
        <td>16:30 ET</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>BARCELONA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/02/2018</td>
        <td>BOLIVIA</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>PORTUAL</td>
        <td>MADRID</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/03/2018</td>
        <td>PUERTO RICO</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>CANADA</td>
        <td>CHICAGO</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2018</td>
        <td>MEXICO</td>
        <td>19:30 ET</td>
        <td>ENGLAND</td>
        <td>LONDON</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you dont need jQuery here. I did two changes to your code and it worked

1. Removed `$(document).ready(` and the closing `)`
2. Added `onkeyup="myFunction()"` on input

Plese check below code.

```css
#myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    #myTable th,
    #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable th {
      width: 20%;
    }
    
    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #myTable tr.header,
    #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax"></script>


<body>
  <p><input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" type="text" placeholder="Search for names.." /></p>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Away</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>08/01/2018</td>
        <td>SPAIN</td>
        <td>16:30 ET</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>BARCELONA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/02/2018</td>
        <td>BOLIVIA</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>PORTUAL</td>
        <td>MADRID</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/03/2018</td>
        <td>PUERTO RICO</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>CANADA</td>
        <td>CHICAGO</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2018</td>
        <td>MEXICO</td>
        <td>19:30 ET</td>
        <td>ENGLAND</td>
        <td>LONDON</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<script>
function myFunction() {

    // Declare variables 
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through first tbody's rows
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

      // define the row's cells
      var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

      // hide the row
      trs[i].style.display = "none";

      // loop through row cells
      for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

        // if there's a match
        if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

          // show the row
          trs[i].style.display = "";

          // skip to the next row
          continue;

        }
      }
    }

  };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add jquery library, and next step is add onkeyup event to your input for start function

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example:

```js
function myFunction() {

  // Declare variables 
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through first tbody's rows
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

    // define the row's cells
    var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    // hide the row
    trs[i].style.display = "none";

    // loop through row cells
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

      // if there's a match
      if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

        // show the row
        trs[i].style.display = "";

        // skip to the next row
        continue;

      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
#myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    #myTable th,
    #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable th {
      width: 20%;
    }
    
    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #myTable tr.header,
    #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <p><input id="myInput" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." /></p>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Away</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>08/01/2018</td>
        <td>SPAIN</td>
        <td>16:30 ET</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>BARCELONA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/02/2018</td>
        <td>BOLIVIA</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>PORTUAL</td>
        <td>MADRID</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/03/2018</td>
        <td>PUERTO RICO</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>CANADA</td>
        <td>CHICAGO</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2018</td>
        <td>MEXICO</td>
        <td>19:30 ET</td>
        <td>ENGLAND</td>
        <td>LONDON</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax"></script>
```

Replace the jquery by the javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function myFunction() ...)
```

by the javascript onload event :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function myFunction() {...} </script>

<body onload="myFunction()">
```

And call myFunction() in the input when keyUp like so

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.."></p>
```

To have this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    #myInput {
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    #myTable th,
    #myTable td {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 12px;
    }
    
    #myTable th {
      width: 20%;
    }
    
    #myTable tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    #myTable tr.header,
    #myTable tr:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <p><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.."></p>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Home</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Away</th>
        <th>City</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>08/01/2018</td>
        <td>SPAIN</td>
        <td>16:30 ET</td>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>BARCELONA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/02/2018</td>
        <td>BOLIVIA</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>PORTUAL</td>
        <td>MADRID</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/03/2018</td>
        <td>PUERTO RICO</td>
        <td>18:30 ET</td>
        <td>CANADA</td>
        <td>CHICAGO</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>08/04/2018</td>
        <td>MEXICO</td>
        <td>19:30 ET</td>
        <td>ENGLAND</td>
        <td>LONDON</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function myFunction() {
    
    // Declare variables 
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through first tbody's rows
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

      // define the row's cells
      var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

      // hide the row
      trs[i].style.display = "none";

      // loop through row cells
      for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

        // if there's a match
        if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

          // show the row
          trs[i].style.display = "";

          // skip to the next row
          continue;

        }
      }
    }

  };
</script>

</html>
```